# Передача значения переменной между скриптами в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Относительно недавно начал изучать такой инструмент как Unity, и возник такой вот вопрос :
У меня есть несколько объектов, к ним присоединен один и тот же скрипт, в другом скрипте я должен получить значение переменной из первого скрипта, но мне нужно что бы при этом для каждого объекта было свое значение данной переменной? Как быть в таком случае? Сразу извиняюсь если вопрос тупой.

Comment: Cоветую начать обучение с основ C# и Unity 3D.
На оф.сайте много стартовых уроков.
Обычно я выкладываю решение проблемы, но чую тут это только усугубит ситуацию.

Comment: Просто пущу в правильном направлении - изучи доступ к функциям класса, модификаторы доступа, и доступ к скрипту с помощъю Юнити.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть несколько объектов и на каждом висит одинаковый скрипт с переменными, то у каждого объекта значения переменных будут СВОИ. Таким образом, например, вы хотите получить значение переменной `a` на объекте под названием `gameObj`, на котором висит скрипт `Logic`. Тогда в другом скрипте, где вы хотите получить эту информацию, команда должна выглядеть так:

```
gameObj.GetComponent<Logic>().a;
```

Переменная a, естественно, должна быть публичной.

А вообще, этот вопрос очень простой и его можно нагуглить за пол минуты. Советую вам так и делать, потмоу что это быстрее, чем ждать неопределенное количество времени, пока вам ответят на сайте

Comment: Благодарю за ответ,почему то нагуглить не получалось,видимо формулировал что то не так

Answer (score 1):

Если переменная **не статическая** то в каждом объекте он имеет своё особенное значение не связанные с другими.

---

Скрипт который висит на множество объектов

```cs
public class Identificator: MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Id;
}
```

---

Скрипт который контролирует всё предыдущие скрипты.

```cs
[SerializedField] private GameObject _ObjectsArray;

private int[] GetAll()
{
    int[] _IdArray = new int[_ObjectsArray.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < _ObjectsArray.Length; i++)
    {
        _IdArray[i] = _ObjectsArray[i].GetComponent<Identificator>().Id;
    }
    return _IdArray;
}

private void Start()
{
    Debug.Log(GetAll());
}
```